# How much of running time performance improvement we can get using java native methods?

Tags: java

How much of running time performance improvement we can get using java native methods?

is that more than 50%

ex- if a method gets 1000 milli seconds to run, then what would be the average time if the same method is implemented as a java native method?

Comment: It depends. it would probably be close to 1000 millis, or perhaps even more because the JIT is smarter than the static C compiler, and invoking a native method has a cost. Using native methods is very rarely a good way of optimizing the performance of a Java program.

Comment: If I need ten minutes to run a mile, how long will it take when I run a different course at a different pace?

Comment: If you have a long running task (like a second) you can optimise it in Java e.g. by using a profiler and using multiple threads.

Comment: It depends. It may be faster, especially if you compile C++ specifically for the processor on which you'll run it; or it may be slower. See [some random benchmark](https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/compare.php?lang=java&lang2=gpp), and [similar question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159373/what-backs-up-the-claim-that-c-can-be-faster-than-a-jvm-or-clr-with-jit)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it depends on how much work you can do in this method. If it just summarizes two numbers, then the overheads will be much bigger than the execution of the method. But if you execute 1000000!, for example, then you can win if your code in C++ is more effective. 
But notice that the JIT compiler in Java is very good right now and it can optimize code dynamically, which is something the C++ compiler can't do. And if you optimize your Java code then C++ version will be slower, because of the JNI overheads.